# How to stop user from login?

Tags: login

I have a Ubuntu PC.I am the root user and have 3 other users too with normal attributes.

How can I stop one of the user from login temporarily ?

with these factors ,

- Don't delete the user
- No attributes change
- a login rejection & a message to him c
  an be look constructive action.

how can I do that ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change that in `usermod`. if you want to lock the user **xyz** then type :

```
sudo usermod --lock xyz
```

This will lock the user until you unlock it manually. To unlock type :

```
sudo usermod --unlock xyz
```

Comment: does that work for ssh logins?

Comment: Yes, This works for ssh logins.

Comment: To stop user form login using authentication token, please check @PokeyBagelHole answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment on the accepted answer (because I am not reputable enough), but the man page for usermod and passwd seems to suggest Sambits answer is not sufficient to completely lock a user out of the system if public key SSH login is enabled:

> -l, --lock
>
> Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
>   password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted
>   value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).
>
> Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be
>   able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key). To
>   disable the account, administrators should use usermod
>   --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).
>
> Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their password.

So to be on the safe side you should do:

```
passwd --lock <user>
```

or

```
usermod --lock <user>
```

**and**

```
usermod --expiredate 1 <user>
```

Then to undo this:

```
usermod --unlock <user>

usermod --expiredate <date> <user>
```